# Play WS standalone for 2.5.x

Tags: web-services, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I want to create a Play web service client outside a Play application. For Play WS version 2.4.x it is easy to find that it is done like this:

```
val config = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder().build()
val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder(config)
val client = new NingWSClient(builder.build)
```

However in 2.5.x the `NingWSClient` is now deprecated - instead the `AhcWSClient` should be used.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a complete example that explains the creation and usage of a AhcWsClient outside of Play. Currently I go with this:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val ws = AhcWSClient()

val req = ws.url("http://example.com").get().map{
  resp => resp.body
}(system.dispatcher)
```

Is this the correct way of creating a `AhcWsClient`? And is there a way of creating a `AhcWSClient` without an `ActorSystem`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using compile time dependency injection, otherwise you would just use `@Inject() (ws: WSClient)`, right?.
There is one example in the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#using-wsclient
So you could write something like this in your application loader:

```
lazy val ws = {
  import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
  import play.api._
  import play.api.libs.ws._
  import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.{AhcWSClient, AhcWSClientConfig}
  import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcConfigBuilder
  import org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHttpClientConfig

  val configuration = Configuration.reference ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseString(
    """
      |ws.followRedirects = true
    """.stripMargin))

  val parser = new WSConfigParser(configuration, environment)
  val config = new AhcWSClientConfig(wsClientConfig = parser.parse())
  val builder = new AhcConfigBuilder(config)
  val logging = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.AdditionalChannelInitializer() {
    override def initChannel(channel: io.netty.channel.Channel): Unit = {
      channel.pipeline.addFirst("log", new io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler("debug"))
    }
  }
  val ahcBuilder = builder.configure()
  ahcBuilder.setHttpAdditionalChannelInitializer(logging)
  val ahcConfig = ahcBuilder.build()
  new AhcWSClient(ahcConfig)
}
applicationLifecycle.addStopHook(() => Future.successful(ws.close))
```

And then inject `ws` to your controllers. I'm not 100% sure with this approach, I would be happy if some Play guru could validate this.
Regarding an `ActorSystem`, you need it only to get a thread pool for resolving that `Future`. You can also just import or inject the default execution context:
`play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext`.
Or you can use your own:
`implicit val wsContext: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatchers.lookup("contexts.your-special-ws-config")`.

Comment: I am not using the dependency injected web service, because I want to use the web service outside of a Play application. The link to the documentation and the extension for a config parser is very useful though.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is the proper way to create the `AhcWSClient` - at least in 2.5.0 and 2.5.1 - as seen in the [Scala API](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-client/)

You can, of course, always take another HTTP client - there are many available for Scala - like [Newman](https://github.com/megamsys/newman/), [Spray client](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-client/), etc. (although Spray is also based on Akka so you would have to create an actor system as well)